# adding multiple classes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How to add a class multiple classes in jquery

i want similar code like below with jquery

```
<div class="common-class item1">text</div>
<div class="common-class item2">text</div>
<div class="common-class item3">text</div>
<div class="common-class item4">text</div>
<div class="common-class item5">text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've to use jQuery's each method

```js
$("div").each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("common-class item" + (i + 1));
})

console.log($("div").toArray())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is to pass a function to `addClass()`. The function itself accepts an `index` argument which you can use to incrementally adjust the class name. Try this:

```js
$('div').addClass(function(i) {
  return 'common-class item' + (i + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
```